# Using induction to prove an equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

> Use induction to show that $n(n + 1) < 2^n$ for all $n \ge 5$.

Assuming is true for $n = 5$,

$5(6) < 2^5$ is true.

How can I prove this using induction?

Comment: Write down the assumption that the statement is true for an arbitrary, but fixed $n$, and then prove the statement is true when $n$ is replaced by $n + 1$. Where are you having trouble?

Comment: How to prove it using n+1. I am aware of that, I know how to prove if an equation is equal to another equation using induction. But idk how to do this one

Comment: Use the fact that $2^{n + 1} = 2^n \cdot 2$ and do some algebra.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose
$n(n+1) < 2^n$.
We want to show that
$(n+1)(n+2) < 2^{n+1}$.

$(n+1)(n+2)
= (n+1)n + 2(n+1)
< 2^n + 2(n+1)
$
by the induction hypothesis.
To show that this is
$< 2^{n+1}$,
we need
$2^n + 2(n+1)
\le 2^{n+1}$
or
$2(n+1) \le 2^n$
or
$n+1 \le 2^{n-1}$.

So, we have reduced showing a quadratic is less than
$2^n$
to showing a linear function is less than
$2^n$
for all large enough $n$.
By a similar reduction,
which I will leave to you,
this can be reduced to showing
that
a constant is less than
$2^n$
for all large enough $n$,
and this is certainly true.

Your turn.

Comment: how did you come to 

(n+1)(n+2)=(n+1)n+2(n+1)<2^n +2(n+1)

Comment: Because the induction hypothesis has to be used somewhere,and that seemed a natural place to use it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

\begin{align*}
2^{n + 1} &= 2^n \cdot 2 \\
&> n(n + 1) \cdot 2 \\
&\vdots  \\
&\ge (n + 1)(n + 2)
\end{align*}

So the problem is reduced to showing why $2n^2 + 2n \ge n^2 + 3n + 2$.

Comment: Can you just show me please?

Comment: @RoyKesserwani No: My hint is quite sufficient for you to try it on your own.